# Access registry values from UWP Application in runFullTrust mode

Tags: windows, uwp, registry, desktop-bridge

I have a UWP app which needs to access registry values. The app is already in runFullTrust mode. Is there a way in which I can access the values without a Desktop Bridge?

__ I have already gone through this:
[How to access registry key in a UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48899692/how-to-access-registry-key-in-a-uwp-app) __
The suggested answer was to launch a  Win32 process from UWP.

> Can I directly get registry value from UWP, without any other Win32 process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I directly get registry value from UWP, without any other Win32 process?

For security reason, UWP does not provide such api to access registry directly, The only way is that indirectly access registry with Win32 process from uwp.