# C# updating or adding value to registry

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, notifications, registry

Why this code is not working

```
    RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(REGISTY_NOTIFICATION_ROOT_PATH, true);
    key.SetValue("NOC_GLOBAL_SETTING_ALLOW_TOASTS_ABOVE_LOCK", bytes, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

After this i am calling close to flush the changes.

```
key.Close();
```

Tried `baseKey .Close();` also but no luck

Ideally it should update the notification setting but it is not. Is there any other way to update `DWORD` value in c#

## Just to make it clear

I am using AppServiceConnection to actually communicate with win32 app and my win32 app is actual updating the Registry.
My question is above code is not updating the registry value, It's not throwing any error but not updating the value also.

Thank

Comment: If you are trying this in a UWP application. You cant access registry. Because UWP is sandboxed environment.

Comment: @Vignesh Through desktop extension we can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't access registry with uwp directly. Please check this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315334/7254781)

> You can read registry values from a Win32 runFullTrust background process launched from a UWP application, and you can write values in registry from an "elevated" Win32 application launched from that `runFullTrust` process.

For details steps please refer [**UWP sends request to desktop extension**](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/) blog. This is code [sample](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am aware of the AppServiceConnection. My question was, above code does not update the value in machines registry?

Comment: Even a desktop bridge app can't modify the registry directly; there is a container that redirects registry writes.

Comment: Hi @PeterTorr-MSFT, Could you share more about the container that redirects registry writes?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes